# Script might have syntax issue I cannot find

Tags: r, syntax

I am still learning R but I put together what I thought was a simple script but I keep getting the following error and Rstudio seems to see a problem in lines 5 and 7 that I don't

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
print"

My script is below:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(FM_2013, aes(x = bioindicator, y = value)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "No. individuals") +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = impact) +
      theme_gray(base_size = 14) +
      facet_wrap( ~ bioindicator, scales = free)

    print(p)
```

Comment: A good first step is to count opening and closing parentheses or brackets: you have 7 `(` but 6 `)`

Answer (score 1):

Missing a `)` here:

```
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = impact))
```